# what will happen when we select wrong images repeatedly in recaptcha?

Tags: recaptcha

I had seen a lot of captcha and recaptcha in websites.so, some one tell me is there any danger by repeatedly selecting wrong images in recaptcha.

Answer (score 0):

CAPTCHA stands for Completely Automated Public Turing test. It is used to make sure the request is made by a real person and not by an automated script. It helps to check spam.

For example, in case of facebook after you have hit like for many posts continuously within a small time interval, it will ask to verify you are a real person by showing its captcha. If you fail to select the right image, you will be barred from liking anymore posts till you get the captcha right.

Similarly the danger of selecting the wrong captcha varies according to the websites. In most cases you would not be able to complete the process that you wanted to undertake in the website like signing up, make a new post or book a ticket etc.

For reasons on why people get captcha wrong check this out [Why people get captcha wrong?](https://www.thebalance.com/what-to-do-when-captchas-dont-work-897057)